# Adding default values for collection of objects inside outer object

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am  trying to add default values to property attributes.I have one class inside which i have other class type injected as list.
I am able to get the default values for all attributes even on dependent class.I want to know is there any way using @value to add one more list of default values of custom objects.
My model classes are-

```
package com.example.test.Model;

    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    @Component
    public class Employee {
     
        @Value("1")
        private Integer id;
        @Value("Anubham")
        private String name;
        
        @Autowired
        private List<Departments>departments;
    
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public List<Departments> getDepartments() {
            return departments;
        }
    
        public void setDepartments(List<Departments> departments) {
            this.departments = departments;
        }
        
    
        public Employee() {
            super();
        }
        
        
    
        public Employee(Integer id, String name, List<Departments> departments) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.departments = departments;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", departments=" + departments + "]";
        }
        }
Another one is:
package com.example.test.Model;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class Departments {
    
    @Value("1")
    private int id;
    
    @Value("computer")
    String subject;

    public Departments() {
        super();
    }

    public Departments(int id, String subject) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Departments [id=" + id + ", subject=" + subject + "]";
    }
}
```

I am getting output as Employee [id=1, name=Anubham, departments=[Departments [id=1, subject=computer]]].
I want to have one more record for departments field.
I wonder is it possible using @value without using any other way.

Answer (score 1):

In your example "Departments" is a bean that is injected into Employee bean. If you want to have multiple departments, you have to create interface/abstraction "Department" and implement it in beans with concrete values that you want (DepartmentA, DepartmentB).

But Value annotation is not meant do inject static content but rather values from properties files. I don't know what you want to achieve this way.